# Would a second publisher ever want a book that didn't do well with the first publisher?

Tags: book, publisher

I have a nonfiction book out which isn't selling well at all. :( And yet, it's gotten rave reviews
from every industry professional who's read it. I'm looking ahead to when it's discontinued and the
rights revert to me. Is it possible that another publisher might want to buy it, despite its
poor sales track record? What if I substantially rewrite and reformat it? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Kristin, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. This is a fantastic first question. Do you know some of the reasons it has sold poorly? Is it perhaps not suitable for academic use? I assume you have spoken to the first publisher who has shown no interest in further promoting it? Good luck and happy writing!

Comment: Thank you for your response! I haven't asked my publisher about it...too embarrassed. :) And I did the majority of the promoting myself.

Answer (score 3):

Not likely unless something new has occurred to make your topic hot.

Your best bet is to republish it yourself by true self-publishing, not through some vanity press that claims to be a self-publisher.

If you do all the promoting (and writing!) then you should make all the profit.  Publishers do not push books unless they expect big sales. The selling part is all up to you.